# Get Facebook Pages Events using graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to fetch facebook events from a pages profile using **facebook graph api**.
The method i was using is like below

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+APP_ID+"&client_secret="+APP_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String access_token = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
String uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/PageName/events?"+access_token.replace("|","%7C");
get = new HttpGet(uri);
String responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

in which APP_ID, APP_SECRET and PageName i am replacing with my details.
There is no issue as its working and i am getting the response also from Facebook as a json array which includes name,start_time,end_time,timezone,location,id of the events, but there is no **event description**.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

By default you don't get **event description** but you can add the same in using `fields` along with other information you require and retrieve more detailed listing. So you need to change your uri to

```
String uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/PageName/events?fields=name,start_time,timezone,location,description"+access_token.replace("|","%7C");
```

To retrieve the required information.

Comment: Does any one know why it doesn't work on this page? https://graph.facebook.com/La-CALLE-Jam-Sessions/events to enter with webbrowser use https://www.facebook.com/pages/La-CALLE-Jam-Sessions/404870736262643?id=404870736262643&sk=events

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Event ID` you get in the response, and use it to get each and every detail of that event from:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID"
```